# Adding nonlinear line with stacked bar plot in r

Tags: r, bar-chart

I would like to add a curved line to fit the dark bars of this supply cost curve (like the red line that appears in image). The height of the dark bars represent the range in uncertainty in their costs (costrange). I am using fully transparent values (costtrans) to stack the bars above a certain level
This is my code:

```
costtrans<-c(10,10,20,28,30,37,50,50,55,66,67,70)
costrange<-c(15,30,50,21,50,20,30,40,45,29,30,20)
cost3<-table(costtrans,costrange)


cost3<-c(10,15,10,30,20,50,28,21,30,50,37,20,50,30,50,40,55,45,66,29,67,30,70,20)

costmat <- matrix(data=cost3,ncol=12,byrow=FALSE)

Dark <- rgb(99/255,99/255,99/250,1)
Transparent<-rgb(99/255,99/255,99/250,0)

production<-c(31.6,40.9,3.7,3.7,1,0.3,1.105,0.5,2.3,0.7,0.926,0.9)
par(xaxs='i',yaxs='i')
par(mar=c(4, 6, 4, 4))

barplot(costmat,production, space=0, main="Supply Curve", col=c(Transparent, Dark), border=NA, xlab="Quantity", xlim=c(0,100),ylim=c(0, 110), ylab="Supply Cost", las=1, bty="l", cex.lab=1.25,axes=FALSE)
axis(1, at=seq(0,100, by=5), las=1, cex.axis=1.25)
axis(2, at=seq(0,110, by=10), las=1, cex.axis=1.25)
```

Image to describe what I am looking for:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYN9r.png]

Comment: What statistical method do you want to use to calculate the position of red line?

Answer (score 2):

I guess it really depends how you want to calculate the line...

One first option would be:

```
# Save the barplot coordinates into a variable
bp <- barplot(costmat,production, space=0, main="Supply Curve", 
      col=c(Transparent, Dark), border=NA, xlab="Quantity", 
      xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0, 110), ylab="Supply Cost", las=1, 
      bty="l", cex.lab=1.25,axes=FALSE)
axis(1, at=seq(0,100, by=5), las=1, cex.axis=1.25)
axis(2, at=seq(0,110, by=10), las=1, cex.axis=1.25)

# Find the mean y value for each box
mean.cost <- (costmat[1,]+colSums(costmat))/2
# Add a line through the points
lines(bp, mean.cost, col="red", lwd=2)
```

Which gives

[image: Straight lines through plot]

Now, you could do some smoother line, using some sort of regression

For instance, using a LOESS regression.

```
# Perform a LOESS regression
# To allow for extrapolation, you may want to add 
# control = loess.control(surface = "direct")
model <- loess(mean.cost~bp, span=1)
# Predict values in the 0:100 range.
# Note that, unless you allow extrapolation (see above)
# by default only values in the range of the original data
# will be predicted. 
pr <- predict(model, newdata=data.frame(bp=0:100))
lines(0:100, pr, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image: LOWSS regression]